# Complex analysis: Prove a meromorphic function to be rational.

Tags: complex-analysis, rational-functions

I come across a problem about complex analysis:

Show that a meromorphic function on the complex plane, which achieves any complex number no more than fixed given times, must be rational.

The only way I know to prove a meromorphic function being rational is to show the infinity is not an essential singularity of the function (thus it can be controlled by polynomial). Following this, we can use Picard's Great Theorem to solve the problem.

I wonder if anyone can help me think of another method. (Without using Picard's Great Theorem.)

Comment: An idea (but I'm not sure) : because of this property, maybe it's possible to substract intelligent polynomials $p_i$ and rationnals functions $r_j$ such that $f - \sum p_i - \sum r_j$ avoid two values, and then you can apply Picard. 
We can already assume $f$ is holomorphic by translating a bit : let $r_i$ the Laurent tail part at each singularity. Then, $f - \sum_{i=1}^n r_i$ is an holomorphic function with the same property (any complex numbers is taken finitely many times). Now, maybe if you find the good $p_i$ it could be possible to finish ... But I'm really not sure.

Comment: my idea was bad. The good argument is the one of George : it has not essential singularity at $\infty$ because else it would take infinitely many values around each neighborhood of $\infty$ (because of Picard theorem). Then, you can just take $f - \sum p_i$ and conclude with Liouville theorem.

Comment: @N.H. But the OP wants to avoid Picard.

Comment: Yes, but the argument of Bernard use also Picard for show that $\infty$ is a pole (that the quick way for seeing it but maybe I didn't see another argument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Show that a meromorphic function on the complex plane, which achieves any complex number no more than fixed given times, must be rational.

If available, Picard's theorem is probably the quickest way to swat this fly [and it yields the result without assuming a *fixed* bound on the number of times a value is attained]. If Picard's theorem is not available or shall be avoided:

Let's call the meromorphic function $f$, and let's call the fixed bound on the number of times any complex number is attained $n$.

If $f$ has at least $k$ poles, then every complex number of sufficiently large modulus is attained at least $k$ times, so $k \leqslant n$. Let $\{\pi_1,\dotsc, \pi_p\}$ be the set of poles of $f$.

Let $m$ be the maximum number any complex value is attained at all (counting multiplicities). Then $m \leqslant n$. Pick $w_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $w_0$ is attained $m$ times (counting multiplicities), and choose $R$ so large that $f(z) \neq w_0$ for $\lvert z\rvert \geqslant R$, and that $\lvert \pi_k\rvert < R$ for all poles of $f$. Choose $\varepsilon > 0$ small enough that $0 < \lvert z - \pi_k\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon \implies \lvert f(z)\rvert \geqslant 1 + \lvert w_0\rvert$ and $\lvert \pi_k\rvert + \varepsilon < R$. Let $G = \{ z\in \mathbb{C} : \lvert z\rvert < R, \lvert z-\pi_k\rvert > \varepsilon\}$. Then look at

$$N(w) := \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial G} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z) - w_0}\,dz.$$

By construction, $N(w_0) = m$, and $N$ is constant on each component of $\mathbb{C}\setminus f(\partial G)$, so we have $N(w) \equiv m$ on some neighbourhood $U$ of $w_0$, which means that every $w\in U$ is attained $m$ times (counting multiplicities) in $G$. By the maximality of $m$, that means no $w\in U$ is attained outside $G$, in particular

$$U \cap f\bigl(\mathbb{C}\setminus \overline{D_R(0)}\bigr) = \varnothing.$$

By the Casorati-Weierstraß theorem, it follows that $\infty$ is not an essential singularity of $f$. Then the rationality of $f$ follows by subtracting the principal parts of $f$ at the $\pi_k$ and (possibly) at $\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!! And I find that w.l.o.g one may ignore multiplicities because of the local behavior of an analytic function near a zero.

Comment: Right. But it was shorter to write "counting multiplicities".

Answer (score 0):

Take the extended complex plane $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty \}$. Introduce a function $f$ that has a punctured neighbourhood at the origin (hence is analytic in a punctured neighbourhood at infinity). The remaining region has finitely many poles hence the collection of poles of $f$ (denoted $a_n$) is finite. Introduce Laurent expansions at one of the poles $a_m$ (for fixed $m$) and at infinity. Look at the nagtive power sections of Laurent expansions at the pole and infinity (call these $l_k$ and $l_{\infty}$ respectively) to derive polynomials of finite length at each pole, and subtract them from $f$. This will give something like
\begin{equation*}
f-\sum l_k-l_{\infty}.
\end{equation*}
Conclude that this result is entire and bounded to get that this is rational.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Without Picard, how do you know that $\infty$ is at worst a pole?

Comment: Thanks anyway, but I wanted to avoid Picard. Daniel provides a perfect answer.

Comment: Yeah, I just realised that Picard is used.